# Button changed to its original shape when pressed from rectangle shape in android?

Tags: android, button

I have few buttons which i designed in rectangle shape.They all looks the way i wanted them to be...but the problem is that when i pressed them ....for a millisecond they turned to its original shape and then returned to custom(i.r.rectangle.)..i tried using different code but it is not working..i want my buttons to remain same (means customized shape) even when pressed.

here is myButton.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip"  />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <stroke android:width="2dip"  />
            <solid android:color="@color/colormain"/>

            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="77dip" />

            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90"

             android:startColor="@color/colormain" android:endColor="@color/colormain" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

this is my login.xml...where i am using those buttons

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context="com.example.zeba.broccoli.Login">

    <!-- Login progress -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logobr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />





        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Already Member ?"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="25dp"/>


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">






                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"

                    android:hint="email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"

                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"

                    android:hint="password"
                    android:imeActionId="@+id/login"

                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/lbtn"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Login"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"

                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:elevation="0dp" />

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fpss"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="Forgot Password" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cAcc"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#FFC107"

                    android:text="Create An account" />



            </LinearLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="Or"
                    android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:textColor="#c4bb99"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tvText"
                    android:background="#c0c0c0"
                    />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvText"
                    android:background="#c0c0c0"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>



            <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:id="@+id/login_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="  connect_with_facebook" />


            <!-- Login Button in the same style as LikeView -->

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="#c0c0c0"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Order Without An Account "
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/gbtn"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton2"
                android:text="As a Guest"

                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:elevation="0dp" />



        </LinearLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/login_progress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: above mentioned code is working fine. i have run it on my machine and it's working fine.

Comment: yes it fine but when u presseed it for a milisecond it return to its original shape...

Comment: try to long pressed it u will come to know the problem'

Comment: i have also tried long press but does not find any issue

Comment: but when i am long pressing it it return to square

Comment: can u please attach the button code also where u are referring  myButton.xml

Comment: i have added the xml file where i am using mybutton.xml

Comment: change  android:layout_width from "match_parent" to "wrap_content"

Comment: but then the width becomes small i need to match it with edittext width

Comment: i have added the answer please see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code u write for pressed state should be same as in default state .if u want same size in pressed state also

so myButton.xml would be

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item  android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="77dip" />

            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90"

                      android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary" android:endColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="77dip" />

            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90"

                      android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary" android:endColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="77dip" />

            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90"

                      android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary" android:endColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: when u long pressed it it returns to its original state..and colour also gone